# Query between date range, INCLUSIVE

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have a TIMESTAMP column named CREATED. I am trying to get all rows between two timestamps INCLUSIVE. This works (exclusive):

```
select id, created 
  from employees 
 where created < '08/11/2014 00:00:01' 
   and created > '08/08/2014 00:00:01' 
 order by created desc;
```

but this does not:

```
select id, created 
  from employees 
 where created <= '08/11/2014 00:00:01' 
   and created => '08/08/2014 00:00:01'
 order by created desc;
```

Why doesn't MySQL recognize the =< and >= symbols in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operators you're looking for are `>=` and `<=` . I believe you're using `=<`.

To represent a TIMESTAMP or DATETIME as a string, you must use `YYYY-MM-DD`. You are using `MM/DD/YYYY`. This will not work properly.

Notice that if you want to choose TIMESTAMP values that occur on a particular date range, the best way to do it is with this sort of query.  This will get items with timestamps from any time on Aug 8,9, 10.

```
select id, created 
  from employees 
 where created >= '2014-08-08'
   and created <  '2014-08-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
 order by created desc;
```

The end of the range (`created < '2014-08-10' + INTERVAL 1 DAY`) takes everything up to but *not including* midnight on the last day of the range you want.

What you have starts one second after midnight. This could mess you up if some of your records don't have any time on them, just date.   If you have a record, for example, dated `2014-08-08` without any time specified, your `00:01` query will not pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

There is another way around: CAST() on the source field.

```
select id, created 
  from employees 
 where CAST(created as DATE) <= '08/11/2014' 
   and CAST(created as DATE) >= '08/08/2014' 
 order by created desc;
```

even better:

```
select id, created 
  from employees 
 where CAST(created as DATE) BETWEEN '08/11/2014'
   and '08/08/2014' 
 order by created desc;
```

This excludes *time* from comparison and works fine for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You must use this syntax: >= or <=.

Answer (score 0):

`=>` is an illegal operator. You will get a syntax error if you attempt to use that. Use `>=` and `<=` for greater-than-or-equal-to and less-than-or-equal-to.

Plus, the proper format for dates is to use `-` for separators between year, month, and day, not `/`.

The `BETWEEN` key word is inclusive:

```
select id, created 
  from employees 
 where created BETWEEN '2014-08-08 00:00:01' AND '2014-08-11 00:00:01'
 order by created desc;
```

When using `BETWEEN`, be sure to put the lower value first.